# Implemet Layout in JAVA

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, graph

> Want to implement this Layout by **LOOP** or dynamically TextView Genrate in this Child LinearLayout with **android:layout_weight="0.5"**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/child_layout"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_range_min"
        style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100px"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_range_min2"
        style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_range_min3"
        style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_range_min4"
        style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_range_max"
        style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="4" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**It may have more or less Text View So i want to add dynamically by loop and also assign weight 0.5 to all text views**

> I am using this but it will not set the weight

```
 LinearLayout MainLL= (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.child_layout);
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
        TextView text = new TextView(this);
        text.setText(""+i); // <-- does it really compile without the + sign?
        text.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
        text.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,0.5f));
        MainLL.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));



        MainLL.addView(text);
    }
```

Comment: Want to Implement in Java Not in XML file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to `text.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.5f));` in your code .

- Set the width of `TextView` `0`
- Set the weight of `TextView` `0.5f`

Try this .

```
LinearLayout MainLL = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.child_layout);
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        TextView text = new TextView(this);
        text.setText("" + i);
        text.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.5f);
        // add margin
        layoutParams.setMargins(10,10,10,10);
        text.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        MainLL.addView(text);
}
```

Comment: Thanks
i want to add text Margin

Comment: LayoutParams has all the attributes you needed. (margin, padding etc).

Comment: where i add params?

Comment: You can try it .

Comment: @KeLiuyue  No it will not work
        layoutParams.setMargins(10,10,10,10);